# I need to pass my amount from application to Paypal using the paypal createorder function in server integration. how can i pass the amount in body.?

Tags: post, paypal, server, integration, fetch-api

```
<script>
        // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container

 paypal.Buttons({

            // Set up the transaction
            createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                return fetch('payPalPayment.html', {
                    method: 'post',
                    body: JSON.stringify( {
                        "purchase_units": [
                            {
                              "amount": {
                                "currency_code": "USD",
                                "value": 100.00
                              }
                            }]
                    })
                }).then(function(res) {
                    return res.json();
                }).then(function(data) {
                    return data.paypalToken;
                });
            },

            // Finalize the transaction
            onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                return fetch('paypalGetExpressCheckout.html', {
                    method: 'post'
                }).then(function(res) {
                    return res.json();
                }).then(function(details) {
                    // Show a success message to the buyer
                    alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
                });
            }


        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    </script>
this above code does not show the amount when I login
```

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered a similar problem, what worked for me is that I've used the basic integration of `createOrder`, since what I need resides in the client.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/#4-set-up-the-transaction

```
paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [{
          amount: {
            currency_code: "USD",
            value: '100.00'
          }
        }]
      });
    },
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
        return fetch('paypalGetExpressCheckout.html', {
            method: 'post'
        }).then(function(res) {
            return res.json();
        }).then(function(details) {
            // Show a success message to the buyer
            alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
        });
    }
}).render('#paypal-button-container');
```